# htcacheclean with "-A" flag only lists 64 cache entries, where are the rest?

Tags: apache-httpd, cache

I have a webserver running Apache. It has caching enabled via `cache_disk_module`.

```
    CacheRoot "/var/cache/httpd/mod_cache"
    CacheDirLevels 1
    CacheDirLength 1
```

I would like to list the URLs of the objects in the cache. If I use the bundled `htcacheclean` command with the `-A` flag to query the cache, it only returns 64 objects:

```
    htcacheclean -A -p/var/cache/httpd/mod_cache
```

Output : 64 lines, each looking like this example:

```
    http://<ACTUAL-URL-HERE> 823 102014 200 0 1603846099818215 1603849699818215 1603846099807137 1603846099818215 1 0
```

The entries which **do** get output, look correct, and contain the expected URLs.

However, if I run a "find" command to count up the number of `.header` files, I get far more than 64:

```
    # find /var/cache/httpd/mod_cache -name '*.header' | wc -l
    30440
    #
```

Apache version is the one currently provided with the CentOS 7.8 distro: version 2.4.6 with various patches backported.

From the man page:

```
   -A     List  the  URLs  currently stored in the cache, along with their
          attributes in the following order: url, header size, body size, status,
          entity  version,  date,  expiry,  request  time, response time, body
          present, head request.
```

...

```
    LISTING URLS IN THE CACHE
           By passing  the -a or -A options to htcacheclean, the URLs within the
           cache will be listed as they are found, one URL per line. The -A option
           dumps the full cache entry after the URL, with fields in the following
           order:
```

...

Can anyone provide clues as to what is happening? How can I dump the full list of cached object URLs using `htcacheclean`?

Answer (score 0):

The hash representation that htcacheclean encodes URLs with is alphanumeric plus @ and _, or 64 possible characters. Setting `CacheDirLength 1` with `CacheDirLevels 1` will give you 64 directories into which caching for all of your site URLs will be divided.

At the end of the subdirectory name, made up of the remainder of the hash (the hash characters that weren't used in the directory name) followed by .header, you may also see .vary. In most cases your server config will have allowed

```
Header set Vary "Accept-Encoding"
```

and possibly another one or more headers, which can trigger different versions of data to be cached for a given URL. A common one that slips through is User-Agent, for which there are many possible values. If so, you could have a large number of header files cached under any of those directories if many different browsers visited the same URL.

Unless you need all of the detail that `htcacheclean -A` returns, try using `htcacheclean -a` instead. The URLs are identical but the format is simpler to parse.

Finally, you mention that your caching directory as `/var/cache/httpd/mod_cache` rather than the default `/var/cache/[httpd or apache2]/mod_cache_disk`. There is no harm in moving it but be sure that this directory agrees with what's in the `/etc/default/apache-htcacheclean` config file.